# How can I make Hive understand the paths of my existing partitioned data?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have existing data on S3 in a partitioned format that should work well with Hive, but the paths don't look exactly like what Hive expects. Is there any way to make Hive aware of my non-standard partition paths?

My paths look like this:

```
s3://some-bucket/pageviews/20120311/ACME1234/example.com/data-file-1
```

Can I somehow tell Hive that to interpret this as

```
s3://some-bucket/pageviews/dt=20120311/key=ACME1234/site=example.com/data-file-1
```

The existing paths are what they are, it's not an option to change them to fit Hive's expectations. I also know that I can manually add all the partitions with `ALTER TABLE pageviews ADD PARTITION (...) LOCATION ...`, but that will quickly become tedious, even if I script it.

Comment: Hive stores info about partitions in it's internal metastore (usually MySQL database), so AFAIK you will have to provide this information through this metastore anyway. I think that using `ALTER TABLE ...` might be quite ok, another option is to use for example Pig to rewrite your data in format that would fit for Hive.

Comment: Rewriting the data is not an option, I think it would be way to heavy to move everything on S3, or copy it all down to HDFS just to get Hive to grok the structure. I'll look into manipulating the metastore and see if that's easier than scripting the partition adding commands.

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution? This AWS blog post suggests a workflow with a lambda function that is triggered when new files are written to s3 and updates the Hive partitions accordingly https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/work-with-partitioned-data-in-aws-glue/

Comment: Yes and no, not with Hive. Since many years I use Athena and it's partition projection feature does exactly what I asked for those 9 years ago.